# Where NCCL dll (Windows 10) must be placed to work with tensorflow in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I compiled NCCL for windows from https://github.com/MyCaffe/NCCL/blob/master/INSTALL.md and get ncll64_164.11.3.dll file.

Where I should place this file so that Pyhton and tensorflow can use it and there were no error like *"InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'NcclAllReduce' used by {{node Adam/NcclAllReduce}}"*, when I use

```
mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
```

I tried to put it to the C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin\  folder, but with no effect.